# Worldwide places reachable by sea/ocean

Tags: data, geolocation, navigation, geonames, places

I'm looking for a list of all populated places(not just big cities/ports) on the world that reside on sea/ocean. The list should contain the place name, latitude and longitude. Does something like that exist somewhere?

UPDATE:
A bit more details: The reason I'm asking for this is because of my project requirement. I need to build a web service which can let people select a place in a list of all possible places in the world(Listed for example in GeoNames DB) but which are on the sea or ocean. The user then gets meteorological data that is related only to places which are on the sea. Like tides, sea temperatures and other more specific info related to the project. Allowing the user to select a place which is not on the sea would simply make no sense.

Comment: Regarding your update, that begs another question. Do you have a list of populated places which actually have the meteorological data you need? This would almost certainly be a better starting point than all populated places in the world.

Comment: That would be an easy way out ;) ... but no, unfortunately the information is derived from satellite data like SST from NOAA and I need to correlate it with latitudes and longitudes of actual places.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nautical navigation apps or dedicated devices, but I'm now wondering if they have some auto route plotting algorithms which let you choose your destination. Obviously they would have to reject places not reachable by sea. Hmm... but then again I kinda doubt that auto routing would make much sense in nautical navigation ...

Comment: Another idea that I'm thinking about is, city/place populated area as a surface, does such data exist? Then I could maybe check if some place surface intersects with the coastline?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going with the routing idea, but it's all about the data and how it's prepared and for what purpose. Additionally, a surface is not going to be able to uniquely identify something as numerous as worldwide populated places, only aggregated or continuous data.

Comment: The routing idea was that if there is maybe an existing dataset present somewhere out there that is being used by the companies who produce nautical navigation systems. Such dataset should already have places marked which can be reached by a boat, because otherwise the software would allow the user to set a route for his boat to some place on land which he can obviously not reach(assuming he has no amphibious craft :)

Comment: Well there is [OpenSeaMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSeaMap) (related to OpenStreetMap). Most commercial nav systems are likely to use proprietary data though.

Comment: As for the place surface idea... I'm not sure I explained that in correct geographical terms. I googled it a bit now and I believe that it is called city boundaries shape(saved in shapefiles). Is there a worldwide database of shapes, that could be used for this purpose? I'm also really hoping that you don't mind that I did not yet accept your answer. I'm just trying to brainstorm this idea for a bit longer. Your answer is very good, but it might fail in cases with smaller cities/villages that are nearby, from which only one is actually on the coast and the others are inland but under 10 miles.

Comment: Realistically, is there any benefit to going more granular than the 1:10m scale Natural Earth data? What is the resolution of the meteorological data? Does it really matter if someone gets readings closer to their village vs. the nearest city? If you want to be able to match against every mapped boat dock in every port in the world you're basically going to be reimplementing OpenSeaMap. Don't underestimate the amount of data that is. OpenStreetMap's raw data dump, last I checked, is over 30GB, and is constantly changing (growing, primarily).

Comment: Also you can obviously adjust the proximity. Maybe 20-30 miles is better for some larger cities whose centers are further inland but still have access to the ocean (e.g. Houston).

Comment: That is exactly why I'm thinking that the proper solution somehow has to take the size of the city into the consideration. I'll leave another comment under your answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be downloading GIS data for populated places and coastlines ([Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) is an oft-recommended source) and performing a proximity analysis using GIS software to exclude all places except those matching some criteria, e.g. within 10 miles of a coastline.

Bear in mind the world is a big place, and the coastlines are very complex geometries (depending on the level of generalization in the data you use). There are a LOT of populated places. Depending on the amount and detail of the data, it will probably take many hours if not days to crunch all of the data.

Perhaps if you explained what you plan to use the data for, a more tailored answer could be provided.

**Update:**

Here is the result of a quick and dirty selection of populated places within 10 miles of coastlines (using Natural Earth's 1:10m scale data):

[image: Screenshot]

CSV data dump: http://pastebin.com/EbPugkMW

Comment: This could be a solution! Although, as you said, a lot of work has to be done. But definitely a nice answer. Thanks. I've updated my question with a more detailed explanation of my intentions.

Comment: After a bit of thinking I believe this could be used but with an addition to somehow take the size of the populated places into the consideration. So that the distance from coastline is less for smaller cities/villages and bigger for big cities. Can I extract the rough estimate of size(for example radius, from center) of places from some source?

Comment: The Natural Earth data has various fields that I did not include in the CSV output in my answer, such as population, bounding box, area and perimeter with varying levels of completion. Check it out for yourself. You can use a FOSS GIS like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) to view shapefiles, as well as the commercial [ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis). There is also an online viewer here: https://koordinates.com/layer/1287-world-populated-places-110-million/